# Set value in an array[3], that the sum of all three values is always 1.0

Tags: java

So I'm working on a Civ like game right now and want to have a setting how taxes are split in gold income, science and luxury goods.

```
private double[] rate = new double[] { 0.4, 0.6, 0.0 };
```

now I wanted to add a methode to change one of the values to a higher or lower value but maintain the overall sum of 1.0 (100%)
but I'm stuck here with how to take or add values evenly from the other two rates

```
    public void setRate (int index, double r) {
    if (r < 0.0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Rate");
    }

    double diff = r - rate[index];
    if (diff > 0) {

        // ?

    } else if (diff < 0) {

        // ?

    }       
    rate[index] = r;
}
```

**EDIT for amitp:**

```
public void setRate (int index, double r) {
    if (rate[index] = 1.0) {
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
              if (i != index) {
                  rate[i] = (rate[index] - r) / 2;
             }
        }
    } else { 
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (i != index) {
                rate[i] = rate[i] * (1.0 - r) / (1.0 - rate[index]);
            }
        rate[index] = r;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest approach is to *rescale* the values.

The values other than the one you're setting currently sum to `1.0 - rate[index]`. You want them to sum to `1.0 - r`. You can therefore scale each of them by `(1.0 - new_value) / (1.0 - old_value)` to preserve the sum.

```
public void setRate (int index, double r) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i != index) {
            rate[i] = rate[i] * (1.0 - r) / (1.0 - rate[index]);
        }
    }
    rate[index] = r;
}
```

This solution avoids:

1. Different code for positive and negative changes
2. Having to handle underflow (something + diff going below 0.0) and overflow (something + diff going above 1.0)
3. A value going from zero to non-zero, or vice versa. If the player set something at 0, then they probably want to keep it there.

Side note: a geometric interpretation is that your three values are coordinates in a cube. You constrain `x + y + z = 1.0` so that puts you on an equilateral triangle embedded in the cube. Thinking about it this way helped me come up with the above solution.

Comment: Note that this solution can still fail, if `1.0 - rate[index]` is 0.0. That will happen when 100% of the resource is assigned to one value, and you try to take away from it. I guess you'd have to handle this special case, probably by evenly distributing the remainder to the other values. If you treat 0 values as epsilon instead of 0.0 then it will work out, I think.

Comment: Would something like this work to write before the for loop?

Look at the Edit.

Comment: That looks like it should work. A unit test for this function should include cases where rates before and after are 0.0 and 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

You could divide diff by two and then subtract it or add it accordingly to the other two.

```
double diff = r - rate[index];
double change = diff/2 * -1; //we need to reverse the operation

for(int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
{
    if(index != i) rate[i] += change;
}
```

Still you should be careful for number precision errors.
For that you could use an int[] where all values sum up to 100.

Comment: You'll also need to handle upper and lower bounds. For example, if you start with {0.4, 0.6, 0.0} and want to increase the first to 0.5, then =change= will be -0.05. You'll end up with {0.5, 0.55, -0.05}.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add to the indexes' value by its self multiplied by `diff`. `rate[i] = rate[i] + rate[i]*diff` where `i` is the other to values other than `index`

```
    double d = 1 - rate[index]       
    double diff = rate[index] - r;
    rate[index] = r;
    index = (index + 1) % 3;           // increment and wrap around index
    rate[index] += diff*rate[index]/d;
    index = (index + 1) % 3;           // increment and wrap around index
    rate[index] += diff*rate[index]/d;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Say I want to raise gold income from 0% to 50%

But with your solution I would add 25% to both science and luxury goods and not raise the gold income (or decrease it). Also this only works when the index is 0. If I want to change the luxury the index is 2. Then I would add 1, have 3 and get an Exception.

Comment: You are correct diff should be defined as follows `diff = rate[index] - r`. Also I didn't include it but right after diff is define the new rate from which ever `index` should be set with the following statement `rate[index] = r`. The index should never equal `3` because any sum of `index + 1` greater than `3` should result in a integer between `0` to `2` do to the modulus operator, `%`. I also forgot some semicolons. I just edited the code and it should would now when put inside your method.